# Can multi laravel based sites be accessed by folder not by port?

Tags: nginx, laravel, directory, virtual

Now, I have  two projects(sites) based on Laravel + PHP + MySQL + Nginx, vistors can access them by typing：

> ```
>   http://www.mysite.com:80
>   http://www.mysite.com:8001
> ```

Can I change the accessing method to virtual folder not by port?

> ```
>   http://www.mysite.com/project1
>   http://www.mysite.com/project2
> ```

The nginx conf files are (at /etc/nginx/conf.d/):

- project1.conf

  ```
  server {
      listen *:80;
      server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
      server_tokens off;
      root /var/www/html/project1/public;
      client_max_body_size 100m;
      access_log  /var/log/nginx/project1_access.log;
      error_log   /var/log/nginx/project1_error.log;
      location / {
              index  index.php index.html;

          if (!-f $request_filename){
                  rewrite (.*) /index.php;
          }
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }


  }
  ```
- project2.conf

  ```
  server {
      listen *:80;
      server_name www.mysite.com;
      server_tokens off;
      root /var/www/html/project2/public;
      client_max_body_size 100m;
      access_log  /var/log/nginx/project2_access.log;
      error_log   /var/log/nginx/project2_error.log;

  location / {
      index  index.php index.html;

      if (!-f $request_filename){
          rewrite (.*) /index.php;
      }
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }


  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The only decent way to do it is by folder and virtual host rather than port.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - an example config will look like this:

### 1 Define your app servers

```
server {
 listen 8080;
 root /var/www/html/project1/public;
  ......
}
```

```
server {
 listen 8081;
 root /var/www/html/project2/public;
  ......
}
```

### 2 Define your proxy server

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
 .....
 location /project1 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    .....
  }


  location /project2 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    ....
  }
}
```